# SourceLink: PDB File Name Casing Does Not Match Repository, Breaking SourceLink

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github, pdb-files, sourcelink

*Is there any way of configuring the linker in Visual Studio so that file names (and paths) embedded in the .pdb file maintain their casing?*

We have a Visual Studio C++/Cli DLL that we'd like to package with NuGet. We want to use SourceLink so that our developers can step into the code, which is hosted on a (private) GitHub repository.

However, when trying to step into the source, Visual Studio (2019 16.2.2) reports an error:

#### Source Link Error

> git-credential-manager.exe: Could not obtain credentials. Process failed with exit code -1.
>   ERROR: The request failed with code 404 : "Not Found". Treating 404 as authentication failure. Some services return 404 instead of 401 for authentication failures.
>
> Source Link URL: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OurCompany/OurRepository/aca51f6e381401234e95b63949d150be04a0ea4a/ourproject/oursubfolder/thefile.cpp

Note that on the file-system and repository the file path uses camel-casing: `Ourproject/OurSubFolder/TheFile.cpp`.

When I replicate the request in Postman using Basic authorisation, it does indeed fail with 404. However, the problem seems to be that the URL constructed by Visual Studio uses lower-case characters for the filename and location; correcting the case makes the request work in Postman. GitHub URLs are of course case-sensitive and that's not configurable.

Opening the .pdb file in Notepad++ shows the filenames are indeed lower-case.

For what it's worth, changing `ignorecase = false` in the git .config file makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. It turns out it's a known bug, and was fixed in VS2019. Unfortunately you need to upgrade to the latest tool chain (v142).